# NumberSequence with different formats

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

We have a scenario where the desire is to have a different number sequence for replacement orders vs sales orders.

Sales Orders have a strictly numeric number sequence defined, ######.
We've created a number sequence for Replacement orders, REP######.

Since both orders live in the SalesTable, this fails when creating the replacement order saying the REP###### number doesn't match the format ######.

1) Is it possible to use two differently formatted number sequences like this?
2) Assuming it is, is there somewhere I can disable some validation to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, this is possible.

2) Take a look how standard AX does this e.g. for fixed assets. You can set up several asset groups with different number sequences that are then used to create numbers for new assets in the groups. So you do not disable a validation, you will customize the code that generates the number to control which number sequence is used to generate the number or to validate the number.

Some further reading:

- [generate different number sequence number for domestic and international sales order](https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/81489/generate-different-number-sequence-number-for-domestic-and-international-sales-order)
- [how to create two number sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992316/how-to-create-two-number-sequences)